# Ubuntu 19.10 low resolution Intel 630 UHD

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, display-resolution, 19.10

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my HP prodesk:

```
uname -a 
Linux Hal 5.3.0-19-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 18 09:04:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I ended with low resolution (1024x768~76Hz) on otherwise nicely working workstation.

Default live installation freezes with black screen. After safe graphics mode I could install a working system with safe mode graphics.

Here is some additional info:

```
 inxi -Gxx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3e92 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
  compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 1024x768~76Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.1 
  compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes 

xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0

sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff memory:4000000000-4000ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have the same problem on [fresh Fedora 31 installation](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?322624-Fedora-31-low-resolution-after-install).